# How do I change or access pandas MultiIndex column headers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Pandas DataFrame, but am having trouble updating a column header value, or easily accessing the header values (for example, for plotting a time at the (lon,lat) location from the header).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["id0", "id1", "id2"])
df.loc[2012]= [24, 25, 26]
df.loc[2013]= [28, 28, 29]
df.loc[2014]= [30, 31, 32]

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns, [66,67,68], [110,111,112]],
                                       names=['id','lat','lon'])
```

Which then looks like this:

```
>>> df
id     id0   id1   id2
lat     66    67    68
lon    110   111   112
2012  24.0  25.0  26.0
2013  28.0  28.0  29.0
2014  30.0  31.0  32.0
```

I'd like to be able to adjust the latitude or longitude for `df['id0']`, or `plot(df.ix[2014])` but at `(x,y)` location based on `(lon,lat)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `df.columns.get_level_values('lat')` in order to get the index object. This returns a copy of the index, so you cannot extend this approach to modify the coordinates inplace.

However, you can access the levels directly and modify them inplace using this workaround.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["id0", "id1", "id2"])
df.loc[2012]= [24, 25, 26]
df.loc[2013]= [28, 28, 29]
df.loc[2014]= [30, 31, 32]

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns, [66,67,68], [110,111,112]],
                                       names=['id','lat','lon'])

ids = df.columns.get_level_values('id')
id_ = 'id0'
column_position = np.where(ids.values == id_)

new_lat = 90
new_lon = 0

df.columns._levels[1].values[column_position] = new_lat
df.columns._levels[2].values[column_position] = new_lon
```

Answer (score 2):

You access `MultiIndex` via tuples.  For example:

```
df.loc[:, ('id0', 66, 110)]
```

However, you may want to access via lon/lat without specifying id or maybe you'll have multiple ids.  In that case, you can do 2 things.

First, use [`pd.IndexSlice`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) which allows for useful `MultiIndex` slicing:

```
df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, 66, 110]]
```

Second:

```
df.stack(0).loc[:, (66, 110)].dropna().unstack()
```

Which is messier, but might be useful.

Finally, the last thing you mentioned.  For a specific row with lon/lat.

```
df.loc[2014, pd.IndexSlice[:, 66, 110]]
```

Comment: As far as I understand, the OP wants to modify the multiindex.

Comment: Yes I'd like to modify the lon,lat. But otherwise, my dataframe has ~1000 times (rows) and ~500,000 IDs (columns), each with a lon and lat. How do I track the location of each column? The `pd.IndexSlice` syntax won't work since there are 500,000 items. Is there a syntax like `df.loc[2014, 'lat']` to get all the latitudes?

Comment: Your example suggests that `2014` will correspond to all `lats`. In that case you can use `df.columns.get_level_values('lat')`. Also, given the dimensions of your problem, perhaps you should consider a transpose? Might get a greater speedup on vectorized operations.

Comment: I'll try a transpose. I thought timeseries need to be index column.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko if you make your comment an answer I can accept it.