# Python - pandas xls import - difficulties removing certain row +

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xls

[miniconda, python 3]

my data .xls to download: (password: stack)
[Download .xls](http://download.hellshare.cz/file-xls/66813293/)

0) 
You can notice that my xls file has big merged cell in the first row and also some merged cells in the rows 2 and 3. Is this a problem? If it is a problem - can i unmerge them somehow?

1)
I want to remove first row of this xls as there is no important info for me. I guess the problem is that the row is merged? I wanted to use df = df.drop([0]) for that, but instead of removing this huge first row, it removes the row with columns headers (starting with "ID klienta"). Why is that?

2)
After I would get rid of the first row, I like to process some numbers from various columns (In my example i want to separate data from "Stav" column). How do I do that? I have seen somewhere that it is possible to index rows/columns just by its header name (the string). For example i wanted to separate data from column with header "Stav" using: Stav = df['Stav']

My code so far is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

print("\n\n*********************************************")
print("My xls processing script\n")
print("*********************************************\n")

#load data 
df = pd.read_excel("file.xls")

#My unsucessful attempt to get rid of first row 
#uncomment this and it will remove the second row instead of the first row
#df = df.drop([0])

#print preview of 6 rows 5 columnts
print(df.iloc[0:5, 0:4])
print("\n\n")

#My unsuccessful attempt to get column date with header 'ID'
Stav = df['Stav']
print(Stav)
```

Output on the console:

```
(xls_env) C:\Users\Slavek\Documents\PythonScripts>python xld_proj.py

*********************************************
My xls processing script

*********************************************

  Lidé, které jsem podpořil                 Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3
0                ID klienta                      Název       Stav  ID příběhu
1                       NaN                        NaN        NaN         NaN
2               zonky214882                       Jeep   na cestě      181187
3               zonky235862  Notebook k práci i relaxu   na cestě      206317
4               zonky230378               Dětský pokoj  v pořádku      199686



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\miniconda\envs\xls_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2525, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Stav'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xld_proj.py", line 20, in <module>
    Stav = df['Stav']
  File "C:\miniconda\envs\xls_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2139, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\miniconda\envs\xls_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2146, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\miniconda\envs\xls_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1842, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\miniconda\envs\xls_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3843, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\miniconda\envs\xls_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2527, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Stav'
```

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Dear sir,

should i remove the snippets of screens? i can do this no problem.

Comment: getting 401 unauthorized

Comment: You are right, the link is not valid anymore. I had enclosed snippets of the excel but I was told by moderator that this is unacceptable form so i had to remove those. 

After i get home from my job i will enclose the example xls again.

Big thanks to this community for the effort inserted so far!

Comment: Download example file.xls should be working now. Feel free to download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the screenshot of your inputted excel file along with the printed dataframe, the problem you're encountering is likely due to the Merged Cells you have in the second and third rows.

I recommend making use of some of the parameters for `pandas.DataFrame.to_excel` that are outlined in docs ([Link Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)). In particular, `header` and `skiprows` should help you.

I've provided an example below, in which I create an excel file (.xlsx) that replicates the issue you have with the merged cells.  Then I copy the .xlsx to be a .xls and read it using `pandas.DataFrame.to_excel` with `header` and `skiprows` spelled out.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import shutil

# Creating a dataframe and saving as test.xlsx in current directory
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=3, index=False, 
header=False)
wb  = writer.book
ws = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

ws.merge_range('A1:C1', 'Large Merged Cell in first Row')
ws.merge_range('A2:A3', 'A')
ws.merge_range('B2:B3', 'B')
ws.merge_range('C2:C3', 'C')

wb.close()

print(df)
#copying test.xlsx as a .xls file
shutil.copy(r"test.xlsx" , r"test.xls")

new_df = pd.read_excel('test.xls', header = 0, skiprows = [0,2])
print(new_df)
```

Expected test.xls file:
[image: Expected test.xls]

`print(new_df)` should show:

```
          A         B         C
0  1.242498  0.512675 -1.370710
1  0.060366 -0.467702 -1.420735
2 -0.198547  0.042364  0.915423
3  0.340909  0.749019  0.272871
4  2.633348 -1.343251 -0.248733
5  0.892257  0.371924  0.023415
6 -0.809030 -0.633796  0.449373
7  0.322960  2.073352  1.362657
8 -0.848093  1.848489  0.813144
9  2.718069 -0.540174  1.411980
```

Comment: Dear sir! Thank you very much for your effort. It is highly appreciated! I will test your suggestions as soon as possible. Unfortunatelly this will be after my return from business trip (after 11.02.2018).

Comment: Thanks this have done the trick. By using the correct parameters you suggested i get now the format i needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the header function option on read in

```
df = pd.read_excel("file.xls", header =[0,1,2])
```

Then you can drop the headers you don't want:

```
 df.columns = df.columns.droplevel([0,1])
```

or something along those lines. The sheet is a little messy since the variable names are scattered across the two sub headers. I'd clean it up so they are all on the same line.

or keep all the headers and see here:
[How do I change or access pandas MultiIndex column headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369317/how-do-i-change-or-access-pandas-multiindex-column-headers)

Comment: Dear sir! Thank you very much for your effort. 

You suggestions are probably valid! I have exactly your thinking --> first clean the mess, got rid of merged cells and after that process the valuable data. 

Your response is highly appreciated! I will test your suggestions as soon as possible. Unfortunatelly this will be after my return from business trip (after 11.02.2018).