# Dataframe add prefix to certain columns on fly while importing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am importing an excel sheet that has two header rows: first row is a common name and second row is column names. I want to prefix each column by the row1 common name.

[image]

My code:

```
df = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx', skiprows=None)
```

Expected output:

```
df.columns = 

['Other Standard_SAIDI With MED', ...]
```

Comment: This can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005577/python-pandas-two-rows-as-column-headers, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369317/how-do-i-change-or-access-pandas-multiindex-column-headers

Comment: Hi, unless there is more to know that what the image shows, you could set `skiprows=0` and then do `df.columns = [f"Other Standard_{col}" for col in df.columns]`